# Service stops automatically in Android

Tags: android, service, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on a Android Project that control Android Device through Speech. For that I am using speech Recognition Service of Google.

Here I have created a service for handling Speech recognition.

But what is going is that after some time this service gets stopped automatically and my device stops responding to the speech of the user.

Then little seconds later, it starts responding again.

So my question here is that how can I stop my service from being destroyed automatically and if possible is there any trick to call my broadcast receiver whenever my service stops?
So that I can create my Broadcast receiver for handling service destruction.

And how can I also stop my device from ringing beep tune when Speak recognition Service going on?

Comment: Do you call startForeground() for your service. This prevent your service from being stopped.

Comment: How can i used startForeground() in my service class? @Demand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to start your `Service` with `startForeground()`. You have to pass it a `Notification` that will be placed in the notification bar permanently. This make your `Service` unstoppable from the system.

As always refer to android documentation for more details.

> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: Thank you. It's work perfectly. But here, when i stop service used "stopForeground(true);" and "stopSelf();" but it's not work. How to stop service from foreground & background?

Comment: From the 'Service' itself you call stopForeground() to remove it from the foreground state and then stopSelf() to tell the system to stop the Service. It should work.

Comment: I try this. It's work when i kill activity then service stop. but button click event on not stop service at a time.